# Wordpress images no longer have srcset and are showing pixalated images

Tags: wordpress, image-size

I just recently moved my wordpress site to another host. There were too many images to import so I imported them through ftp and then used the `[Add from Server plugin][1]` to ensure my image id and such were in the database.

Images on my new site now show up however they are very pixalated and blurry as they are showing a small image blown up to 100%. I have tried regenerating thumbnails but have had no luck. It is the saem theme with the same code.

My old site image look like this:

[image]

Where my new site looks like this:

[image]

The images are all in the media library and i I swap them in one by one it wokrs but there are hundreds of posts. Is there a way to get this to work manually somehow? I thought this is what Regenerate Thumbnails was supposed to do. thanks for any help you can give.

I just check and my excerpts are not showing either.

Comment: I believe Regenerate Thumbnails should do the job, but there are several of those plugins with similar names. Did you use [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)?

Comment: Correct that is the one I have used.

Comment: Probably Add from server plugin made some changes and that caused a problem. But it's not very clear to me what for you needed that plugin

Comment: So I had to many image (3000) or so when I moved the site, So the I could never get wordpress to import attachments. I tried various plugins and it would just time out our return an error. So I manually copied the uploads folder to the server. When I did that the images could not be found by wordpress, Add from server was how I got wordpress to recognize my images again. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you uploaded images via FTP. I assume folder structure is intact - year/month folder structure inside uploads folder. That should work without any other actions. Did you try? I don't understand part where you say *"to ensure my image id and such were in the database"*. If you take your old database and upload to your new server, then why should some ids change? :/

What I want to say is that migrating WP from one host to another is just - copy all files, copy database and that's it. If you are changing domain of the site, then you must search/replace database also (but I don't think that's the case here).